# Populating html text box values based on drop-down selection in a Dynamic Add/Remove HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

**Problem Statement: ** : I have a drop-down named as Cars and input text-box named as price. If the entry value is one, the data is getting correctly displayed such as the if the input selection is Volvo, its showing as 125000000, but when-ever I am clicking on Add button to add a new row to the html form, if I select Audi this time, all the text-box values getting changed to 185000000. It would be very helpful, if anyone guide me on this.

**GUI**
[image: HTML_ADD_REMOVE_FORM]

**GUI--2
**

Now, when I am selecting a different value from the drop-down list, all the values are getting changed. I want only the particular option value to be displayed.

[image]

**Code - JQUERY**

```
 $(document).on('change', 'select[name="cars[]"]', function() {
            var total = 0;
            $('select[name="cars[]"]').each(function() {
                //total += parseInt($(this).val());
                var get_cars = $(this).val();
                if (get_cars == 'volvo') {
                    $(price).val(125000000);
                } else if (get_cars == 'saab') {
                    $(price).val(145000000);
                } else if (get_cars == 'mercedes') {
                    $(price).val(165000000);
                } else if (get_cars == 'audi') {
                    $(price).val(185000000);
                }
            });
        });
```

**Code - HTML**

```
<td><select class="form-control" name="cars[]" id="cars">
                                <option value="" disabled selected>--Select--</option>
                                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                                <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
                                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
                            </select></td>
                        <td><input class="form-control price" type="text" name="price[]" id="price" required=""></td>
```

**Current Output : ** - If the entry value is one, the data is getting correctly displayed such as the if the input selection is Volvo, its showing as 125000000, but when-ever I am clicking on Add button to add a new row to the html form, if I select Audi this time, all the text-box values getting changed to 185000000.

**Expected Result** : If I click on Volvo - it would show as 125000000, if I click on Audi, it would show as 185000000
I am attaching the full-code for reference.

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var html = '<tr><td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="txtFullname[]" required=""></td><td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="txtEmail[]" required=""></td><td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="txtPhone[]" required=""></td><td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="txtAddress[]" required=""></td><td><select class="form-control" name="cars[]" id="cars"><option value="" disabled selected>--Select--</option><option value="volvo">Volvo</option><option value="saab">Saab</option><option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option><option value="audi">Audi</option></select></td><td><input class="form-control price" type="text" name="price[]" id="price" required=""></td><td><input class="btn btn-danger" type="button" name="remove" id="remove" value="Remove" required=""></td></tr>';
            var x = 1;
            var max = 5;
            $("#add").click(function() {
                if (x <= max) {
                    $("#table_field").append(html);
                    x++
                }

            });
            $("#table_field").on('click', '#remove', function() {
                $(this).closest('tr').remove();
                x--;

            });

        });

        $(document).on('change', 'select[name="cars[]"]', function() {
            var total = 0;
            $('select[name="cars[]"]').each(function() {
                //total += parseInt($(this).val());
                var get_cars = $(this).val();
                if (get_cars == 'volvo') {
                    $(price).val(125000000);
                } else if (get_cars == 'saab') {
                    $(price).val(145000000);
                } else if (get_cars == 'mercedes') {
                    $(price).val(165000000);
                } else if (get_cars == 'audi') {
                    $(price).val(185000000);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form class="insert-form" id="insert_form" method="post" action="">
            <hr>
            <h1 class="text-center">Dynamically add input field & insert data</h1>
            <hr>
            <div class="input-field">
                <table class="table table-bordered" id="table_field">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Full Name</th>
                        <th>Email Address</th>
                        <th>Phone No</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th>Cars</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Add or Remove</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="txtFullname[]" required=""></td>
                        <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="txtEmail[]" required=""></td>
                        <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="txtPhone[]" required=""></td>
                        <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="txtAddress[]" required=""></td>
                        <td><select class="form-control" name="cars[]" id="cars">
                                <option value="" disabled selected>--Select--</option>
                                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                                <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
                                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
                            </select></td>
                        <td><input class="form-control price" type="text" name="price[]" id="price" required=""></td>
                        <td><input class="btn btn-warning" type="button" name="add" id="add" value="Add" required=""></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <center>
                    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="save" id="save" value="Save Data">
                </center>

            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In your example, `price` in `$(price).val(125000000)` is used but not defined. I recommend traversing the DOM: `$(this).parent().parent().find('.price').val(125000000)`

Comment: Also, you reuse the same id in each row. If you need ids, make them unique, such as by adding the row number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, `price` in `$(price).val(125000000)` is used but not defined. I recommend traversing the DOM like this:

`$(this).parent().parent().find('.price').val(125000000)`

Also, you reuse the same id in each row. If you need ids, make them unique, such as by adding the row number.